# “Get a 3-Legged Token with Authorization Code Grant” is not OAuth 2.0 RFC complaint and generates an Error 400

Tags: oauth-2.0, autodesk-forge

I've implemented application capable of acquiring OAuth access token through authorization process using authorization code grand type. I've used it successfully with Google API services but I have a problem when I use it with AutoDesk Forge API services. I have suspicion that OAuth AutoDesk does not confirm well with OAuth 2.0 specification.

My application issues this HTTP POST request of the shape:

```
POST /authentication/v1/gettoken HTTP/1.1
Host: developer.api.autodesk.com
Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=authorization_code&code=SplxlOBeZQQYbYS6WxSbIA
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fclient%2Eexample%2Ecom%2Fcb
```

Here I send client_id and client_secret as username and password for Basic HTTP authorization. But I get an error:

```
{"developerMessage":"The required parameter(s) client_id,client_secret not present in the request","userMessage":"","errorCode":"AUTH-008","more info":"http://developer.api.autodesk.com/documentation/v1/errors/AUTH-008"}
```

However, OAuth specification says in chapter 2.3.1 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3.1):

```
The authorization server MUST support the HTTP Basic
authentication scheme for authenticating clients that were issued a
client password.
```

You can see example of such request that server MUST support in chapter 4.2.3 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3):

```
 POST /token HTTP/1.1
 Host: server.example.com
 Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 grant_type=authorization_code&code=SplxlOBeZQQYbYS6WxSbIA
 &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fclient%2Eexample%2Ecom%2Fcb
```

And AutoDesk wants it differently as per its documentation:

```
  curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/gettoken'
  -X 'POST'
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  -d '
    client_id=obQDn8P0GanGFQha4ngKKVWcxwyvFAGE&
    client_secret=eUruM8HRyc7BAQ1e&
    grant_type=authorization_code&
    code=wroM1vFA4E-Aj241-quh_LVjm7UldawnNgYEHQ8I&
    redirect_uri=http://sampleapp.com/oauth/callback
  '
```

(Here, as you can see, AutoDesk expects client_id and client_secret to be in the POST request body.) That is additional way that server MAY support as written again in chapter 2.3.1 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3.1):

```
Alternatively, the authorization server MAY support including the
client credentials in the request-body
```

So, am I right that AutoDesk Forge API service only supports optional way and apparently doesn’t support mandatory way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, am I right that AutoDesk Forge API service only supports optional way and apparently doesn’t support mandatory way?

Affirmative - the only authentication format that's supported can be found [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/gettoken-POST/).

Comment: Thanks, Bryan! That is unfortunate, of course. Makes it hard to code for the standard . Will require some user interface option or two requests instead of one, if one way it fails then try another way. And it is not recommended by the standard to merge both into one request (with authentication in both, body and header). Is it common practice to do it in body or were there some reasons to go this way, that might help me understand it better and make my decisions more intelligent?

Comment: Without double checking with our architect my educated guess would be it might have been deemed less secure to put the client secret in the header in the form of basic auth (given the general impression that very auth type is insecure...) - although technically it's not exactly different to putting it in the body...